How to generate and configure SSL/TLS certificate for private subdomain app.myorg-local.net
I am working on one internal project where we are using private subdomain (app.myorg-local.net) to host our react application using NGINX in RHEL9 environment. Please guide me how to obtain SSL certificate and install and configure on nginx in RHEL9 environment.
We have generated internal SSL certificate and installed on NGINX and we are getting. Invalid certificate error.
